# How to rewrite the following inline code to a block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this piece of code:

```
.tap { |m| el(m, 3, 4) { |l, f| puts "Patient: #{l}, #{f}" } }
```

And I would need to assign the values `l` and `f` to variables and later save it to database.

I've tried something like this:

```
.tap { 
  m.each do
    puts m.inspect
  end
}
```

but this results in a syntax error.

How do I assign the values to variables in this case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `l` and `f` *are* variables, although their scope is only the enclosing block. If you do a `saved_l=l` inside the block, they are now stored to a different variable, but you need to convince Ruby, that `saved_l` belongs to an outer scope. If this variable is mentioned the first time inside the block, the scope would be block-local as well. This can be solved by explicitly setting `saved_l=nil` before entering the block.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context to your code? Maybe there's a cleaner solution that extracting information within `tap`.

Comment: Is `m` an array? A relation? A patient? What does `el` do? Will you have a single `l` and `f`? Maybe explain what you are trying to do in a little more detail? Why do you need the `tap` ?

Comment: "but this results in a syntax error." – So does your original code. Since neither of your two code snippets are legal Ruby code, it is quite hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the values to variables defined in an outer scope, e.g.:

```
str = nil
'foo'.tap { |s| str = s }
str #=> "foo"
```

or use an object to hold the value(s):

```
values = {}
'foo'.tap { |s| values[:str] = s }
values #=> {:str=>"foo"}
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefan. One more questions, how do I assign there more values? I tried something like this: `.tap { |s, t| values[:s] = s, values[:t] = t }`, but the output was something like this: `{:t=>"t", :s=>["s", "t"]}` instead of expected `{:t=>"t", :s=>"s"}`. Am I overlooking something? Thank you

Comment: @user2932090 that `,` has to be a `;`. Comma is used for multiple assignment, e.g. `a, b = 1, 2`

Answer (score 0):

While you might set the variables from the outer scope directly, it violates all known to me good practices. I would go with a dedicated object to store the values:

```
▶ class Test
▷   attr_accessor :foo, :bar
▷   def set(foobar)  
▷     @foo, @bar = foobar    
▷   end  
▷ end  
▶ test = Test.new; [42, 3.14].tap(&test.method(:set))
#⇒ [42, 3.14]
▶ test
#⇒ #<Test:0x0055aac1e0b2f0 @bar=3.14, @foo=42>
```

Comment: Your `test` is my `str`, isn't it?

Comment: @Stefan I was ready to answer this comment from the scratch :) Here `test` variable is mentioned in the calling context (and yes, I understood it’s a shortcut to the block notation, but here it’s called in the outer context, then it’s method is passed to the block, making it look like the encapsulation is not broken.) Maybe I am mistaken, though. Mutating everything is evil, btw.